# Limited friend list in Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I received a question from one of the users of my application, and I am doubting if this is a programming bug on our end. When requesting the friend list of the user, the API only returned 480 out of 580 friends. Is the friend list limited to this number? Or is it likely that the other 100 users have very strict privacy settings regarding external applications? If none of these two questions is true there must be a bug in my coding, but before I dive in I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Is there a pagination link on the results? many calls default to 500 results and need pagination to get to the second page. The discrepancy between 500 and 480 can usually be explained by privacy settings

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To tackle the 500 results-limit, would it help to add &limit=1000 to the query?

Comment: That or add an offset and retrieve it in two batches of maximum 500 results - bear in mind that some users will have over 1000 friends

Comment: Do you know if there's an API call that gives me the total number of friends? That way, I know how many pages I can expect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ?limit=5000 or a higher amount because the default limit is 500. Otherwise, make multiple calls using the next and prev navigation links included in the json response. The reason you are getting 480 instead of 500 is probably because users have changed their privacy settings or opted out of Facebook application platform entirely.  Their query first gets 500 friends, and then removes the people that have opted out.